# Colloquial expression for “penis”

Tags: word-choice, colloquial, taboos

What's the best way to refer to a penis in a casual, but not necessarily overtly sexual, way, akin to saying *dick* in English?

Take for example [this sentence from the autobiography of Ice-T](https://books.google.cl/books?id=mxxRFFNnDpcC&pg=PA81&dq=%22my+dick%22+pain&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IQm4VLjXIMulyAScq4HgBw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwATgy#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> I had a catheter up my dick and I just lay there [...] with my whole shit exposed.

I feel confident that no one would expect Ice-T to refer to his male member as a penis while recounting his “gangster life,” especial when the phrase *fucked up* follows shortly afterwards. I would also not expect anyone to imagine he has its sexual function in the forefront of his mind (he may be concerned for it on a sexual level, but a body in pain is first of all a body in pain, and not an apparatus in pain).

Comment: Regarding the discussion @Grantwalzers answer below: seems we need a bit more context - what do you need the expression for?

Comment: It seems you need to add a criterion for people here to able to guess what you mean by *best way*. Otherwise it is gonna cause endless discussion and time-wasting. So I vote closing (as for now).

Comment: @Takkat If you meant _penis_: The title is  
> Colloquial expression for penis  
Do you consider _penis_ colloquial?  If you meant _Penis_: I'd like for you to tell me if it _can_ be used; that's why I asked.

Comment: @user1076174 well, we are having trouble to understand your question here. On one hand your are asking for a German translation to "penis", which obviously is "Penis". On the other hand you ask for a translation of a vulgar slang word "dick" but ask it to be "casual but not necessarily sexual". Your question needs much more elaboration to be answerable in a way other than just giving an almost endless list of dictionary  entries. None of these expressions will qualify as "best" but this is a prerequisite for the StackExchange Q & A format.

Comment: @Takkat Where did I ask for the German translation of _penis_? I merely _referred_ to the object with that word, as it is the most generic term for it. As to your objection to what I actually asked, I would love a long list of words that fit my question, but, so far, I haven't found a single word that I can confidently place on that list.

Comment: As for the question of my using the word _best_, it's evident, on this very page, and almost anywhere a question is asked on the internet, that people will read what they want to when dealing with a question. I included that word so that those people who would like to read, understand, and sit with the question a moment will understand that I know that there might not be an exact translation, and that I will gladly accept a translation that does a moderately good job, or even the best job, when compared to all the other German words that refer to the penis.

Comment: To get your question reopened you need to [edit] it in a way it fits to our site (see [help]). You may also be interested in [this meta post on how to ask](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences).

Comment: @Stephie I don't _need_ it for anything. I'd like to know the answer for personal enrichment. Id' like to know the best way to refer to a penis in German in a casual, but not necessarily overtly sexual, way so that I will then know the best way to refer to a penis in German in a casual, but not necessarily overtly sexual, way.

Answer (score 4):

The vulgar expression *dick* pretty much corresponds to

> Schwanz *(tail)*

A less vulgar option (although slightly more context is needed) is

> (jemandes/sein) Ding *(someone's/his thing)*

Comment: No, I wasn't allowed to use 'vulgar' words in the title.

Comment: Can _Schwanz_ also have a purely descriptive, non-sexual, aspect to it?

Comment: @user1076174 That depends on how you define non-sexual, but it's unlikely. Descriptive <---> scientific <-/-> colloquial.

Comment: Well, _rod_ is a much more descriptive word than <---/---> the more "scientific" 'erect penis,' and it's <------> colloquial, but since it describes an erection, it's necessarily sexual. A _dick_ can be either flaccid or erect, allowing it to have a purely descriptive, non-sexual, aspect to it, in certain situations.

Comment: @user1076174 For a cat, sure. For a man, definitely not. You want "Geschlechtsteil" or similar descriptive terms for that.

Comment: This answer is correct, but not complete. I don't know how to make it complete without going into the vulgar direction. (Is "Pimmel" vulgar? "Tito Pimmel" isn't, but it refers to a meal where the meat is formed like a penis.)

Comment: @user1076174 If for you, *dick* can "have a purely descriptive, non-sexual, aspect to it, in certain situations", then *Schwanz* can, too. But I don't see how that is the case - it's the one thing to have sex with we're talking here about, after all. Also, how is *rod* more descriptive/less sexual than *erect penis*?

Comment: @TheBlastOne I'm not sure, but I think that it's not vulgar (at least it wasn't originally, I wouldn't use it today), as it is/was used among kids. Interestingly, that would make it non-sexual.

Comment: _Rod_ paints a much more immediate picture than _erect penis_ to anyone who's seen a rod and has at least a vague understanding of erections.

Comment: @KilianFoth What would you translate "Geschlechtsteil" to in English? "Sexual member" has no ring of the colloquial, which is what I need from this word I am seeking.

Comment: Here is an example. I feel confidant that no one would expect Ice-T to [refer to his male member](https://books.google.cl/books?id=mxxRFFNnDpcC&pg=PA81&dq=%22my+dick%22+pain&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IQm4VLjXIMulyAScq4HgBw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwATgy#v=onepage&q=%22my%20dick%22&f=false) as a _penis_ while recounting his "gangster life," especial when the phrase "fucked up" follows shortly afterwards. I would also not expect anyone to imagine he has it's sexual function in the _forefront_ (he may be concerned for it on a sexual level, but a body in pain is first of all a body in pain, and not an apparatus in pain.)

Comment: I would argue that *dick* [is indeed a vulgar/sexual term](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=dick): You are assuming that so-called "vulgar" terms are never uttered on TV or by children... which makes me wonder what planet you're from ;)

Comment: I never heard somedody use the word "Ding" when talking about a penis.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Rather generic _Ding_ and _Teil_ are usually used either with a possessive pronoun like _mein_ or a qualitative attribute, which usually makes the context sexually explicit. They may be teutonisms, though. JFTR: _Schniedel(wutz), Dödel_ (Northern), _Lörres_ (Western), _Piep-/Piller-/Pullermann/-hahn_ (children), _kleiner_ <Name>, _bestes Stück_.

Answer (score 3):

One could add the following:

- *Der Schniedel* … tallywacker
- *Der Pullermann/Pillermann* … pee-pee

which are usually used for the penis when talking to (and about) kids.

You may also use:

- *Der Piepmatz* … which normally refers to a bird (I don't recall having heard of it, but it appears as a synonym of penis [here](http://www.sprachnudel.de/tag/penis) where you may find other synonyms!)
- *Der Schaft* … shaft
- *Die Rute* … rod (but i usually heard this use in case of animals like dogs)
- *Der Dödel* … putz (I also never heard it in this context, but found it on the link mentioned above!)

Comment: As you say, these terms are only used in certain contexts, so don’t really qualify as “casual, but not necessarily overtly sexual”. Anyway, we now have collected most synonyms listed at [Open Thesaurus](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/Penis) and [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thesaurus:Penis) on this page. _Lümmel, Nudel, Prengel, Schwengel_ and _Zipfel_ are also frequent in some places, also _Johannes_ in the saying _An der Nase eines Mannes erkennt man seinen …_

Comment: *Pimmel* we must not omit. And too bad *Gemächt* isn’t exactly colloquial (maybe when used *scherzhaft*).

Comment: @Medi1Saif: No, why?

Comment: @dakab as i didn't use any of the words in my post and *Pimmel* already is quoted by Hubert

Comment: @Medi1Saif: The comment was supposed to add to or suggest addition to your answer. Useful answers to topics like this one usually have to be extensive, and that certainly does not rule out mentioning a word that already was given in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, any word for the male (or female, for that matter) genitals will entail a degree of vulgarity because sex is considered a [taboo topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_taboo) in most cultures, even if it is much less so in some than others. This leads to the use of [euphemisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) such as e.g. *sex organ(s)*/*Geschlechtsteil*, *member*, *manhood*, etc.: Generally, the more direct the reference, the more vulgar it is. *Penis* has escaped a degree of this vulgarism due to its placement in a high register of English (and German), which coincides with its Latinate origins (many things have a "fancier" Latinate word and a corresponding "dirtier"/more "casual" Germanic word referring to it).

As stated above, knowing Ice-T (not personally, of course), I would say that a "German" Ice-T would very much use the word *Schwanz* in the given context. Alternatively, *Pimmel* is slightly "sillier" while still being mildly vulgar. However, just like the word *dick* in English, both *Schwanz* and *Pimmel* can be used either in sexual or non-sexual contexts and are also both vulgar but only mildly so.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refer to a penis in a casual, but not necessarily overtly sexual way, in German language, you might use the word

> der Penis.

This is a latin word and means "tail" in English or "Schwanz" in German. It was used by ancient romans as a dirty word and was started to be used as "official" word in medicine in 19<sup>th</sup> century, and from its medical use it was imported into english as well as German as a word to name this organ in a serious way. In german it can be used in a casual way too.

The German Word, that is (almost) free of sexual connotation is

> das Glied.

often also

> das männliche Glied.

But »*Glied*« is rarely used in colloquial talk.

Also the German translation of the latin word *penis* is used in German to name the male organ. This word is

> der Schwanz.

I think, that »Schwanz« is the most used German word for the penis. It has a sexual connotation, but it is not so strong as in the most other alternatives. And therefore I think, that of all German alternatives »Schwanz« has the greatest similarities to *dick*.

Another word with a similar degree of sexual connotation is

> der Pimmel.

But, as I did notice, *Schwanz* is more often used than *Pimmel*, but there might be great regional differences, and also differences that come from the social status.

Answer (score 1):

Two words that haven’t been mentioned yet but I like pretty much:

- Zipfel
- Schwengel

However, I feel that they may even be less offensive than *Schwanz* which would admittedly be a better choice here from what I hear.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a close friend, you might start a little bit of humerous conversation until it's ok to bring in terms that you would use non-offensively on strangers too. I guess if your communication is anywhere close to formal, you wouldn't even want to talk about these kinds of things, unless necessary.

But as a straight-forward word, I'd recommend to you "Genital"

> Wie lange littest du an dem Syndrom, das Reizungen an deinem Genital verursachte?

Otherwise, there's some anti-serious videos on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPPYXTHGE44) counting tens of words for whatever giggle-term out there.

Answer (score -3):

Rarely used expressions are also "Fleischpeitsche" (meat whip), "Kronjuwelen" (crownjewels) or "Schniepi".

Comment: In my understanding, *Kronjuwelen* refers to the testicles or the male genitalia as a whole – not just to the penis. The other ones do not fit into the context presented by the question.